# How do I change users in FileZilla?

Tags: linux, command-line, sudo, filezilla

I am using FileZilla to log in to an SFTP host with my credentials. However, I need to use an equivalent of `sudo su - user` (as used in linux) to change the user. There are no passwords set for this general user, and hence direct login is not allowed.

What FTP command can I use with the "Enter custom command.." option in FileZilla to switch users after connecting?

(This is required so I can transfer files as a different user and not my login.)

Comment: Repost your question on SuperUser.

Answer (score 11):

SFTP protocol doesn't support changing user in the middle of transfer session (so no case to login and then change user with some custom command). But you can launch sftp server under needed user using sudo, by changing SFTP client configuration. Don't know whether this trick is supported by FileZilla, but it's supported by PuTTY or WinSCP. There in the sftp server settings you can specify something like "sudo /bin/sftp-server" in order to launch transfer session under different user.
For example, instruction how to do this with WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_su#sudo